# Silly confusion about the substitution for proving the convergence of limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In proving the convergence of limits, my friend pointed out to me that I use a substitution method which is not valid. For example, if I want to prove that $$\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}$$
converges to $0$, I would use the substitution $x=r\sqrt{\cos{\theta}}$ and $y=r\sqrt{\sin{\theta}}$. Clearly, $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ implies $r\to 0$. 
But then $$\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}=\frac{r^5\cos{\theta}\sin^{3/2}{\theta}}{r^4}=r \cos{\theta}\sin^{3/2}{\theta}.$$
Now, since $\cos{\theta}\sin^{3/2}{\theta}$ is bounded, we have $$r \cos{\theta}\sin^{3/2}{\theta}\to 0$$
So $(x,y)\to(0,0)\implies r\to 0\implies \frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}=\frac{r^5\cos{\theta}\sin^{3/2}{\theta}}{r^4}\to 0 $

The problem that has been pointed out to me is that, 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^5\cos{\theta}\sin^{3/2}{\theta}}{r^4}$$
doesn't necessarily hold. But they couldn't tell me why it is wrong. I've seen that if the function $f$ that we're taking the limit is continuous, then $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=b$ and $\lim_{y\to b}f(y)=c$ implies $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=c$ but I'm not sure how this applies in this situation. So my question is, in what situation is making the substitution valid? and what is wrong with applying this method in this situation?

Edit: I found a solution which seems to work.

we have $$(a^2+b^2)\geq\frac{(a+b)^2}{2}$$ so 
$$(x^4+y^4)\geq\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}\implies \frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}\leq \frac{2x^2y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}xy^{3/2}}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2$$ 
Now, use polar coordinates, 
so $x=r\cos{\theta}, y=r\sin{\theta}$ gives 
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}xy^{3/2}}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}r^{5/2}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}^{3/2}}
{r^2}\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{2}r^{1/2}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}^{3/2}
\right)^2$$
$\sqrt{2}r^{1/2}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}^{3/2}$ clearly converges to $0$. We can use the squeeze theorem to show that $\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}$ also converges to $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that substitution is not valid. Since you deal with the square roots of $\cos\theta$ and of $\sin\theta$, that substitution only provides information concerning what happens if $x,y\geqslant0$. So, if$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }xy>0\\-1&\text{ if }xy<0,\end{cases}$$then your method would lead you to the conclusion that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=1$, whereas, in fact, that limit doesn't exist.

Comment: So is the criteria for a valid substitution bijectivity?  Or is it more restrictive?

Comment: That's a vast question, but surjectivity, at least, is quite important here.

Comment: Does this sort of argument work with polar coordinates? or is it dependent on the function?

Comment: With polar coordinates there is not problem of this sort whatsoever.